# ReactJS, How to get the oldest and newest date from array using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this array:

```
DatosFechas = ["2020-04-29", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-30", "2020-04-30", "2018-01-22"]
```

And I would like to get the oldest or the newest date from a given range.

Ths function that trying to get work:

```
function ObtenerMaxMinRangoFechas(DatosFechas) {
    let moments = DatosFechas.map(x => moment(x)),
    maxDate = moment.max(moments)
    return maxDate

}
```

Thx

My date array is longer, just for the purpose of this posting it´s reduced.

This is the error:

[image]

Is not giving me the maxdate.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I updated the resulta that i am obtaning. Is not giving me the max date from the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned `maxDate` variable is actually a `Moment` object. You can simply format it to get the desired result like:

```js
const DatosFechas = ["2020-04-29", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-30", "2020-04-30", "2018-01-22"]
function ObtenerMaxMinRangoFechas(DatosFechas) {
    let moments = DatosFechas.map(x => moment(x)),
    maxDate = moment.max(moments)
    return maxDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
}

console.log( ObtenerMaxMinRangoFechas(DatosFechas) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I see now!

Answer (score 2):

Sort the dates array and grab the last one.

```js
DatosFechas = ["2020-04-29", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-30", "2020-04-30", "2018-01-22"]
const sortedDates = DatosFechas.sort((a, b) => moment(a) - moment(b));
console.log('NEWEST Date',sortedDates[sortedDates.length-1])
console.log('OLDEST Date',sortedDates[0])
```

Note: You don't really need `moment` for your case. You can use js inbuilt `Date` feature. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property)

---

Comment: great and to obtain the newest?

Comment: Reverse the call back logic inside `sort`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing great, you have done right. Just problem is that you have to formant your return `moment` object instead of returning it as an object.

Use it-

```
function ObtenerMaxMinRangoFechas(DatosFechas) {
    const moments = DatosFechas.map(x => moment(x));
    const maxDate = moment.max(moments);
    return maxDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In what format do you want to return the first and last date? Here is an example with an array of the first and last string:

```js
let dates = ["2020-04-29", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-30", "2020-04-30", "2018-01-22"]

const getFirstAndLastDate = (dates) => {
  dates = dates.sort()
  return [dates[0], dates[dates.length - 1]]
}

console.log(getFirstAndLastDate(dates))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Moment.max` seems to be returning an **moment object** rather than a **string** in the format you want. to get the string format, you'll need to call format and pass the format you want, like this

```
moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

let's put this together,

```
function ObtenerMaxMinRangoFechas(DatosFechas) {
    let moments = DatosFechas.map(x => moment(x)),
    maxDate = moment.max(moments).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return maxDate
}
```